# Does "eating less" stimulate cell starvation?

Tags: cell-signaling, autophagy

[2016 Nobel Prize in physiology or medicine](https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/medicine/laureates/2016/press.html) was given for the study of autophagy.
Judging from the description, a healthy cell responds to starvation (and other types of stress) with autophagy.
Does starving of the organism for short amount of time (around a day) cause cell starvation? And, can we say that starving for short amount of time stimulates autophagy?

Comment: What is "short amount of time"?

Comment: @MartinKlvana around a day